# Почему бот не отвечает на сообщения в группе, хотя если писать ему напрямую, то всё работает?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Бот не отвечает на сообщения в группе (но если напрямую ему писать, то работает).

Я создала [группу для теста](https://t.me/gynui), и у меня не получается его туда добавить.

```
import telebot
import config
import dbworker
bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

name = '';
surname = '';
age = 0;
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def start(message):
    if message.text == 'к':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Как тебя зовут?");
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_name); #следующий шаг – функция get_name
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Напиши "к"');

def get_name(message): #получаем фамилию
    global name;
    name = message.text;
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Какая у тебя фамилия?');
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_surname);

def get_surname(message):
    global surname;
    surname = message.text;
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Сколько тебе лет?');
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_age);

def get_age(message):
    global age;
def get_age(message):
    global age;
    while age == 0: #проверяем что возраст изменился
        try:
             age = int(message.text) #проверяем, что возраст введен корректно
        except Exception:
             bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Цифрами, пожалуйста');
    from telebot import types
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(); #наша клавиатура
    key_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Да', callback_data='yes'); #кнопка «Да»
    keyboard.add(key_yes); #добавляем кнопку в клавиатуру
    key_no= types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Нет', callback_data='no');
    keyboard.add(key_no);

    question = 'Тебе '+str(age)+' лет, тебя зовут '+name+' '+surname+'? пришла скупиться';
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=question, reply_markup=keyboard)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    if call.data == "yes": #call.data это callback_data, которую мы указали при объявлении кнопки

        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'давай тебе что-то подберем : )');
    elif call.data == "no":
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'нет : )');

def user_entering_age(message):
    # А вот тут сделаем проверку
    if not message.text.isdigit():
        # Состояние не меняем, поэтому только выводим сообщение об ошибке и ждём дальше
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Что-то не так, попробуй ещё раз!")
        return
    # На данном этапе мы уверены, что message.text можно преобразовать в число, поэтому ничем не рискуем
    if int(message.text) < 5 or int(message.text) > 100:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Какой-то странный возраст. Не верю! Отвечай честно.")
        return
    else:
        # Возраст введён корректно, можно идти дальше
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Когда-то и мне было столько лет...эх... Впрочем, не будем отвлекаться. "
                                          "Отправь мне какую-нибудь фотографию.")
        dbworker.set_state(message.chat.id, config.States.S_SEND_PIC.value)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["photo"],
                     func=lambda message: dbworker.get_current_state(message.chat.id) == config.States.S_SEND_PIC.value)
def user_sending_photo(message):
    # То, что это фотография, мы уже проверили в хэндлере, никаких дополнительных действий не нужно.
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Отлично! Больше от тебя ничего не требуется. Если захочешь пообщаться снова - "
                     "отправь команду /start.")
    dbworker.set_state(message.chat.id, config.States.S_START.value)@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
  if message.text == "Привет":
      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, сейчас я расскажу тебе гороскоп на сегодня.")
  elif message.text == "/help":
      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши Привет")
  else:
      bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help.")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def cmd_start(message):
    state = dbworker.get_current_state(message.chat.id)
    if state == config.States.S_ENTER_NAME.value:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Кажется, кто-то обещал отправить своё имя, но так и не сделал этого :( Жду...")
    elif state == config.States.S_ENTER_AGE.value:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Кажется, кто-то обещал отправить свой возраст, но так и не сделал этого :( Жду...")
    elif state == config.States.S_SEND_PIC.value:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Кажется, кто-то обещал отправить картинку, но так и не сделал этого :( Жду...")
    else:  # Под "остальным" понимаем состояние "0" - начало диалога
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет! Как я могу к тебе обращаться?")
        dbworker.set_state(message.chat.id, config.States.S_ENTER_NAME.value)
bot.remove_webhook()
bot.polling(none_stop=True,interval =0)
```

Comment: краткость сестра таланта

Comment: а имеет прикреплять код в данном случае?

Comment: я добавила код . но думаю дело не в нем

Comment: *не отвечает на сообщения в группе* - какой группе? *напрямую* - это как? уточните ваш вопрос и полностью опишите ситуацию, если хотите чтобы вам смогли помочь

Comment: я создала группу для теста : https://t.me/gynui и у меня не получается его туда добавить

Comment: Напрямую написать, это через @ к нему обращаться?

Comment: у меня не получется вызвать его в группе через @

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У ботов по-умолчанию включены настройки приватности.
Если бот в группе не администратор, то он видит только те сообщения, которые адресованы лично ему.
Т.е. сообщение `/start` бот не получит, а `/start@MyBot` - получит.

Есть 2 варианта решения:

1. Отключить `Privacy Mode` в настройках бота у [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather)
2. Дать боту права администратора

Answer (score 0):

я не добавила id чата, поэтому код не работал.